# Find Pattern in Python List

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I want to loop through a `python` list and group patterns of data.

The list is, in fact, a list of dicts with various properties which can be divided into 3 types. I will call these `A`s, `B`s and `C`s.

The pattern I am looking for is each `A` type dict with the previous `C` dict plus the previous two `B` dicts. Each `A` and `B` dict should only exist in one group.

**Example:**

```
Original List (data): [A1, B1, B2, B3, C1, A2, A3, B4, B5, B6, B7, C2, B8, C3, A4]
```

Desired Result: `[[B2,B3,C1,A2], [B7,B8,C3,A4]]`

**Conditions:**

As you can see from the example an `A` should be ignored if there are no previous `B` and `C`'s (e.g. `A1`) or if there is another `A` before these `B` and `C`'s (e.g. `A3`). Also there may be rogue `C`s that can also be ignored (e.g. `C2`).

**What I have Tried:**

```
# Extract indices for all A elements
As = [i for i, item in enumerate(data) if item['Class']=="A"]

 # Loop through the A's
for a in As:

    # Ensure the A isn't too close to the start of the list to have sufficient prev elements
    if a > 2:

        e = [data[a]]

        # For each prev item
        for index in range (a-1,0,-1):

            # Get the item
            item = data[index]            

            if (len(e) > 3) :
                continue #Exit once there are 4 items in the list 
            elif (len(e) > 1) :
                searching = "B"; # Start by seraching for B's
            else:
                searching = "C"; # After a B is found go to C's

            if item['Class']=="A": # If another A is found before the list is filled end the search
                break
            elif item['Class']==searching:
                e.append(item)


        if data[index]['Class']=="A":
            continue
```

This works but feels like really terrible code! Any better solution suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You should read into finite state machines and write one to recognize your pattern. That should be an easy way to solve it. Or maybe this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: you **must** use list comprehension, for some reason? if not, there are some easy solutions

Comment: Each item in the list is a dict with a key-value pair showing it's type (A/B/C). I used a list comprehension to find the indices of any A's in the original list but if there is a different way of achieving the same I have no tie to using this method at all.

Comment: I have updated this to reflect a (terrible) working solution I have made

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Regex in your case

```
import re

# Convert to Class string representation
# example 'ABBBCAABBBBCBCA' 
string_repr = ''.join([item['Class'] for item in data])

# Compile pattern we are looking for
pattern = re.compile(r'BC*B+C+B*A')

# Find last possition of patterns in string_repr
positions = [match.end() - 1 for match in re.finditer(pattern, string_repr)]

# Use indices from positions on data list. Thay match
your_As = [data[i] for i in positions]
```

Comment: It produced  BBBCA and BCBCA. All match

Comment: This only finds the A's, but not the corresponding B's and C's to do the full grouping as requested in the question.

Comment: Thanks, this part works for finding the A's but as @HannesOvrén commented does not find the B's and C's to go with them.
I have changed the Regex to this: (B)C*(B)C*(C)B*(A).
It works for this example, do you think it is sufficient?

Comment: @user2071737   I think (B)C*(B)C*B*(C)B*(A) is a better choice.